# If you're programming using C#, are you actually talking to the computer's CPU?

Tags: development

If you're programming using C#, are you actually talking to the computer's CPU?

Comment: Can you elaborate on that question? It's a bit unclear what you mean with "taking to the computer's CPU".

Comment: No. You're writing code which is translated to an Intermediate language first - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_language . Since you mention C# see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language

Answer (score 6):

Well yes and no, if you use a high level language such as C#, Java or something similar you are writing a program, so yes you are giving instructions to the CPU, but there is an intermediate layer between your code and the CPU that is basically translating your high-level code to the processor. In case of C# that will be .NET Framework, JVM for Java and so on.

Then you have your low-level languages where you have to be very aware of the CPU your code will run on. Assembler is one of those languages.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_language) hosts a plethora of great information on the subject.

Comment: P. Aginic: Good explanation, but there are even more layers: .NET language -> .NET bytecode/MSIL -> win32 -> CPU opcode/machine code. Of course, another .NET platforms e.g. linux/mono have their specific layers below MSIL. For different CPUs it's the same, every architecture has it's own.